# Naoqi python SDK error in raspberry pi during installation

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi3, nao-robot

> import naoqi
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "/home/pi/Downloads/pynaoqi-python2.7-2.1.4.13-linux32/naoqi.py", line 7, in 
>       import qi
>     File "/home/pi/Downloads/pynaoqi-python2.7-2.1.4.13-linux32/qi/**init**.py", line 72, in 
>       from _qi import Application as _Application
>   ImportError: /home/pi/Downloads/pynaoqi-python2.7-2.1.4.13-linux32/**_qi.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

**I tried all the things below**

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=${DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/home/pi/Downloads/pynaoqi-python2.7-2.1.4.13-linux32/

export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/home/pi/Downloads/pynaoqi-python2.7-2.1.4.13-linux32/

sudo ldconfig -v too
```

**nothing works**

Comment: If anyone know this help

Comment: If you look in Downloads/pynaoqi-python2.7-2.1.4.13-linux32/site-packages, is _qi.so in there ?

Comment: Yes the file _qi.so is there but the error comes anyway

Comment: A naive question: do you build it specifically for raspberry ?

Comment: @Sasidarank then it seems the path is somehow wrong. It looks for _qi in the wrong directory. Can you try export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=${DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/home/pi/Downloads/pynaoqi-python2.7-2.1.4.13-linux32/site-packages/ ?

Comment: No didn't built it. It is already available for linux that why I tried it in raspberry pi. I tried only because it works perfectly in my ubuntu desktop.

Comment: I also tried that too DYLD PATH that also not working

Comment: Is anyone tried the naoqi python SDK in raspberry pi 3 ??

Answer (score 0):

the problem because pynaoqi was build for x64/x86 architechture; Raspi's processor is ARM architechture. So it can not work on rasp.